# Jquery/Javascript -- Find parent's sibling's children's child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Take for example a html like the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
       <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <div>
             <a class="delete-btn"></a>
       </div>
       <ul>
          <li>
          <div>
               <div>
                    <a data-record-id="9">I need to grab this, from a click on 'delete-btn'</a>
               </div>
          </div>
          </li>
       </ul>
   </body>
<html>
```

I need to add a click event to the item a that has the class 'delete-btn', and grab the data-record-id from the `<a></a>` that has the data-record-id of 9. This can and will change, and assume I have no possibility of adding the data-record-id to the original delete button.

Basically, I have a list of vitals signs for a date, I want to give the user the ability to delete all signs for a date. All children of the date label will have the same record id, which I need to grab.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
$(this).parent().next().find('a')
```

I don't know why do you get that error.

See http://jsfiddle.net/3Zkz9/

```
$('.delete-btn').click(function(){
    var $a=$(this).parent().next().find('a');
    alert($a.attr('data-record-id')); // gives 9
});
```

Comment: I tried that, and when I tried to do .attr('data-record-id') I get the error that you can't call method attr of undefined.

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
$('.delete-btn').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).parent('div').next('ul').find('[data-record-id]').attr('data-record-id');
    // use id
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out,

```
$($('.delete-btn')[0]).parent().next().find('a').attr('data-record-id')
```

though you will have to make appropriate changes,
like run an each loop through all the elements later or whatever you want to do. but this works!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter) function to just extract those anchors with `data-record-id=9`:

```
$('a.delete-btn').on('click', function(e) {
    var $recid9 = $('a').filter(function() {
        return ($(this).data('record-id') == 9);
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/CyKab/